# Republishing Intentionally Expired Job Listings

Tags: feature-request, support, status-bydesign, jobs

I want to expire a job listing I have on Careers because we are very close to hiring a particular candidate.

But if I do expire the job listing, can I republish it without cost should the candidate we intend on hiring not end up actually taking on the position?

There are still about 15 days left on the job listing, so I don't want to just lose those 15 days should I republish it later.

Comment: Can a feature request be [status-bydesign]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now that's not possible without our intervention. 30 day listings are one shot products. If you expire a listing, that product is gone regardless of how long the listing ran.

Now, if you want to pause the listing, we can always manually reinstate the listing on our end. I'm not quite prepared to offer that anyone that reads this post, but in your case if you e-mail careers@stackoverflow.com I'll take care of it for you.

Comment: Probably not important enough to worry about for now. Thanks for the offer, though. Pausing a listing would be a cool feature, however.